# find_one MongoDB Ruby Driver

Tags: ruby, mongodb

It looks like the current Ruby Mongo Driver 2.0.4 no longer has the find_one method. I can only find it in reference to GridFS.

How can I retrieve a single document from Mongo using the official ruby driver? The find method returns a collection not a single object.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`find()` returns a `CollectionView` which is a not-yet-executed query which behaves like an enumerable. To find just the first record:

```
find.limit(1).first
```

(Yes, it is annoying)

Comment: Yes, it sure is annoying. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I think what's even more annoying is that I cannot find a clear "upgrade to 2.0" guide somewhere. The only thing I could find is the release notes here: https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-ruby-driver/releases/tag/2.0.0

...saying:

> The 2.0.0 release of the driver is a rewrite and provides absolutely no backwards compatibility

Answer (score 3):

You can use `.find(condition).first`

If you are searching by ID, you can also do

```
@coll = Coll.find( hash["_id"] )
```